# Bitbaking recipe doesn't install DEPENDS

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

I have got bbappend file for one of the recipe in meta-tegra. Appends are dependent on dtc, which has been added to DEPENDS:append section. On bitbaking this recipe, dtc is not getting built.

Below is tegra-bootfiles_%.bbappend

```
# Hack: The fetch task is disabled on this recipe, so the following is just for the task signature.
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${BPN}:"
SRC_URI:append:p3768-0000-p3767-0000 = "\
    file://tegra234-mb1-bct-gpio-p3767-hdmi-a03.dtsi \
    file://tegra234-mb1-bct-pinmux-p3767-hdmi-a03.dtsi \
"

DEPENDS:append = " dtc dtc-native"

addtask do_process_eeprom before do_install

do_process_eeprom() {
    dtc -I dtb -O dts ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dtb > ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dts
    sed -i 's/gbe-uphy-config = <0x08>/gbe-uphy-config = <0x09>/g' ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dts
    dtc -I dts -O dtb -o ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dtb ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dts
    rm -rf ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dts

    sed -i 's/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x100>/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x0>/g' ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/BCT/tegra234-mb2-bct-misc-p3767-0000.dts
    sed -i 's/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x100>/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x0>/g' ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/BCT/tegra234-mb2-bct-misc-p3701-0002-p3711-0000.dts
    sed -i 's/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x100>/cvb_eeprom_read_size = <0x0>/g' ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/BCT/tegra234-mb2-bct-misc-p3701-0002-p3740-0002.dts

    # Define the text to add
    text_to_add='        reg@322 { /* GPIO_M_SCR_00_0 */\n            exclusion-info = <2>;\n            value = <0x38009696>;\n        };\n'

    # Use sed to add the text after "tfs {" in the file
    sed -i '/tfc {/a\'"$text_to_add"'' ${S}/bootloader/t186ref/BCT/tegra234-mb2-bct-scr-p3767-0000.dts

}


# Hack: As the fetch task is disabled for this recipe, we have to directly access the files."
CUSTOM_DTSI_DIR := "${THISDIR}/${BPN}"

do_install:append:p3768-0000-p3767-0000() {
    install -m 0644 ${CUSTOM_DTSI_DIR}/tegra234-mb1-bct-gpio-p3767-hdmi-a03.dtsi ${D}${datadir}/tegraflash/
    install -m 0644 ${CUSTOM_DTSI_DIR}/tegra234-mb1-bct-pinmux-p3767-hdmi-a03.dtsi ${D}${datadir}/tegraflash/
}
```

On executing `bitbake -v tegra-bootfiles`, following error occurs -

```
dtc -I dtb -O dts /home/user/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/L4T-tegra-35.4.1-r0/Linux_for_Tegra/bootloader/t186ref/tegra234-bpmp-3767-0001-3509-a02.dtb
/home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/p3768_0000_p3767_0000-poky-linux/tegra-bootfiles/35.4.1-r0/temp/run.do_process_eeprom.1462074: 141: dtc: not found
+ bb_sh_exit_handler
+ ret=127
+ [ 127 != 0 ]
+ echo WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.
+ exit 127

+ ls -A

+ [ deploy-source-date-epoch ]
+ set +e

+ tar -I pzstd -8 -p 12 -cS -f /home/user/poky/build/sstate-cache/4e/90/sstate:tegra-bootfiles:p3768_0000_p3767_0000-poky-linux:35.4.1:r0:p3768_0000_p3767_0000:10:4e90edf4eefa9b94a2e7fc008d6fa4b569642b6903ff9a967da1236cec8b2dc1_deploy_source_date_epoch.tar.zst.Ij3TcnB1 deploy-source-date-epoch

ERROR: tegra-bootfiles-35.4.1-r0 do_process_eeprom: ExecutionError('/home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/p3768_0000_p3767_0000-poky-linux/tegra-bootfiles/35.4.1-r0/temp/run.do_process_eeprom.1462074', 127, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/poky/build/tmp/work/p3768_0000_p3767_0000-poky-linux/tegra-bootfiles/35.4.1-r0/temp/log.do_process_eeprom.1462074
ERROR: Task (/home/user/poky/meta-tegra/recipes-bsp/tegra-binaries/tegra-bootfiles_35.4.1.bb:do_process_eeprom) failed with exit code '1'
```

I am expecting tegra-bootfiles to install dtc as part of its process but dtc build is no getting initiated.

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks